# Processing 4D input with 2D Convolution in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am having trouble understanding how 2D Conv calculations are done on 4D inputs. Basically, this is the situation, I have an image of height, width, channels = 128, 128, 103. I want each of these 103 channels to be processed individually as if I'm inputting them to the network one by one. Would the following line work?

```
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
model1 = tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential()
model1.add(Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape = (128, 128,103,1), padding='same'))
```

[image]

I want to avoid splitting the image and inputting it into the network as 103 batches of (128,128,1)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D?version=nightly

> 4+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (channels, rows, cols) if `data_format='channels_first'` or 
> 4+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (rows, cols, channels) if `data_format='channels_last'`.

(by default: `data_format='channels_last'`.)

You are passing a 5D tensor of shape (batch_shape, 128, 128, 103, 1).
I suggest you reshape your tensor into something that will yield a shape like this one `(None, 128, 128, 103)`.

Also please change `input_shape = (128, 128,103,1)` to `input_shape = (128, 128,103)`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. If I change the input_shape to (128,128,130), will 130 channels be processed individually? or as a cube?

Comment: What do you mean as a cube ?